# How can I calculate the frame rate of scrolling?

Tags: android, android-widget

I have a scroller view like the launcher workspace. How do I know the frame rate while the view is scrolling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you are interested in a number of in-between repaints per second, upper bound of which is determined by a processing delay between consecutive repaints. You may be able to measure this beforehand by a [smooth scroll of one vertical pixel](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#smoothScrollBy%28int,%20int%29).

Comment: What do you mean the processing delay between consecutive repaints? Sometings I do in onDraw() which lead to the delay?

Comment: I thought that by 'frame rate while the view scrolling' you mean that you have smooth scrolling enabled http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#setSmoothScrollingEnabled(boolean) and you are asking how often/sec Android puts in inbetween frames.

Comment: What I propose is a way to measure the upper bound, by finding how fast they can scroll your view once.